# How can I compare a string and a char array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

In my program I'm trying to compare my char array `asterixA[]` to a String `word` in an if condition like:

```
if (word.equals(asterixA))
```

but it's giving me an error. Is there any other way I can compare them?

Comment: Convert the `char[]` into a `String`, and then use `equals`.

Comment: Make it a habit to go through the Javadocs. It'll help you deal with such things.

Answer (score 17):

you have to convert the character array into String or String to char array and then do the comparision.

```
if (word.equals(new String(asterixA)))
```

or

```
if(Arrays.equals(word.toCharArray(), asterixA))
```

BTW. if is a conditional statement not a loop

Comment: Thanks, still pretty new to this

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be taking the "A String is an array of chars" line too literal. `String`'s `equals` method states that

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

It all depends of the circumstances, but generally you compare two objects of the same type or two objects belonging to the same hierarchy (sharing a common superclass).

In this case a `String` is not a `char[]`, but Java provides mechanisms to go from one to the other, either by doing a `String -> char[]` transformation with `String#toCharArray()` or a `char[] -> String` transformation by passing the `char[]` as a parameter to `String`'s constructor.

This way you can compare both objects after either turning your `String` into a `char[]` or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

do as follows: `if (word.equals(new String(asterixA))) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the arrays:

```
if (Arrays.equals(asterixA, word.toCharArray()) {}
```